# Android Studio not starting up on windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

So I have installed android studio and also downloaded JRE and JDK succesfully; even tested it through command prompt. I have even made enviroment variables that tell me to paste the path of JDK to JAVA_HOME and bin path to PATH. But still whenever I start Android studio It gets stuck after almost loading i.e. on this screen

[image]

Please help; I have even tried reinstalling everything from the scratch but m still stuck. And even rebooted my PC every time to make sure it is been done properly.

PS: When I monitored this process through task manager It consumed Disk and memory till the point where it is in screen shot after that disk usage goes to 0 and memory stays constant. I know its what it is supposed to be but just mentioning

Thanks in advance

Comment: have u tried running as admin?

Comment: Which JRE and JDK versions are you using?

Comment: Usually cause by either: Rouge Java versions (competing JREs / SDKs, Windows is very bad at handling multiple java versions as opposed by Linux) or: An AVD wasn't shut down cleanly. Clear our all lockout files for the avd in question and restart. Otherwise it is very hard to tell with only limited information available.

Comment: Believe me; I recently updated my windows 8 to10 and formated everything. and this was my first java installation. Although I do think that I should probably downnload jdk and jre for 32 bit and then adding same path to enviroment variables can do something. you think?

Comment: and I have tried as an admin no help

Comment: You only need the JDK for android-studio. You can also try: disconnecting your android device. adb kill-server
& adb start-server. Clear out your android-studio %app-data% files. Uninstall Android-SDK if separately installed. Remove ANDROID_SDK_HOME, ANDROID_HOME from your Environment variables. Update to the latest Android-Studio version. Add this property: -Ddisable.android.first.run=true (Also kill all lingering java processes via the task manager between tries)

Comment: BTW I did search for lockout files but they clear out as soon as I do "end task" from task manager.

Comment: See my answer, for completeness I added all suggestions from here and a few more.

Comment: I cannot thank enough

Comment: I am using 1.8.0_101 JDK and JRE version

Answer (score 10):

Delete the AndroidStudio folder resolved my issues (after a big upgrade).

On Windows 10 x64 2020 this is

> %APPDATA%\Google\

There you'll find an AndroidStudio folder. Delete it.

As documented in Android docs
https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Comment: This was part of solution for me. I also had to set the environment to use the java system shipped with android - so JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Answer (score 0):

Here is a collection of things to try to rectify the situation. Without more information this is very broad:

- rouge JAVA versions (competing JREs / SDKs, Windows is very bad at handling multiple java versions as opposed by Linux)
- An AVD wasn't shut down cleanly. Clear our all lockout files for the AVD in question and restart
- disconnect your android device during startup
- adb kill-server & adb start-server during the hang
- clear out your android-studio %app-data% files
- uninstall Android-SDK if separately installed
- remove ANDROID_SDK_HOME, ANDROID_HOME from your environment variables
- update to the latest Android-Studio version
- add this property: -Ddisable.android.first.run=true
- ensure to have permissions to read/write to %appdata%
- ensure enough disk space is available
- ensure enough RAM is available

**Also kill all lingering JAVA processes via the task manager between tries.**

***EDIT:***

Also, sometimes you may just need to wait a while. When I was behind a **proxy** that limited the download of zip and rar files Android Studio downloaded gradle and dependencies with a whopping **10kb/s**. After 10 minutes I connected my cellular network and started up in 10 seconds. (Also check if the sites are not blocked completely)

Comment: so I have checked and tried that adb kill-server and adb start-server gives this error " 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
can this be sole reason as I have not actually started the server till the studio finally starts up.

Comment: Studio should start it for you. If will freeze on startup if the server is hanging, that's why kill && start fixes it in that case. Your issue seems to be that you don't have adb in your path in order to access it from your cmd prompt. It should be unrelated to the issue.